# Codegniter4 - Como realizar una conexión a la base de datos paso a paso

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Estoy realizando pruebas con codegniter4 y requiero conectarme a la base de datos alguien podrá explicarme paso a paso en el manual vi que debo entrar a la carpeta `app/config/Database.php`.

Y está seria la configuración que es un ejemplo:

```
 */
public $defaultGroup = 'default';

/**
 * The default database connection.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'admin',
    'database' => 'coba',
    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
];
```

Como sé yo que me conecto correctamente a la base de datos para empezar a desarrollar: a mí me sale este mensaje:

> Whoops! We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later

He buscado videos tutoriales pero la mayoría lo muestran en codegniter3 yo estoy usando la versión 4 por lo que he buscado y solo pude llegar hasta ahí.

Answer (score 1):

'''

```
* @package CodeIgniter
 */
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use Config\Database;


class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ['url', 'form', 'text'];

    protected $security, $session, $validation, $botones;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // E.g.:
        // $this->session = \Config\Services::session();

        $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
        $this->validation = \Config\Services::validation();
        $this->security = \Config\Services::security();
        $this->faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        $this->pager = \Config\Services::Pager();
        $this->botones = config('Botones');        

        $this->db = Database::connect();
    }

}
```

'''
He aqui un fragmento del controlador BaseController.
la linea $this->db = Database::connect(); abre la conexion. Con esto se consigue que todos los controlers que heredan de BaseController ya tienen la conexion a la BD abierta

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, es importante revisar [answer], te sugerimos evitar realizar varias publicaciones como respuesta, puedes realizar solo una y editarla, saludos.